# QMAKE: Link static library against another static library

Tags: c++, qt, static-libraries, qmake

I have a QMAKE staticlib project (libtest.a) that deppends to ther subproject (liblogger.a)

I try to add his to test.pro:

LIBS += -L$$OUT_PWD/../libs/logger/ -llogger

PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$OUT_PWD/../libs/logger/liblogger.a

but, finaly, qmake pack .a library without liblogger.a

**ar cqs libtest.a libtest.o**

I can't use QMAKE_AR += or QMAKE_LIBFLAGS +=, and I need to build static library with this AR command

**ar cqs libtest.a libtest.o ../libs/logger/liblogger.a**

any idea?

Comment: A static library is really nothing more than a simple archive of object files, and as such they are not really *linked*. If you want to use multiple static libraries you either need to link the executable program (or shared library) with *both* the static libraries, or you extract the object files to create one large library containing all object files from both the static libraries.

Comment: Yes, I know, but I want to pack all object files into my static library. I can do it manually with AR command, but I don't know how to do it with QMAKE

Comment: My recommendation is to *not* do that, and use both libraries when linking your executable program.

Comment: you are true, but I want to build a static library with _main() funtion, and call this _main funtion from main(). Why? Because is more easy for LGPL relink license

Answer (score 0):

One possible strategy is to add a custom build target  that depends on both your project (libtest.a) and the subproject (liblogger.a), which outputs the unified library you're looking for by calling ar.

You can check qmake's documentation [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-advanced-usage.html#adding-custom-targets).

Afterwards, set that custom build step as a dependency of the project that includes `main()`.